# NSRunAlertPanel shows up behind the "active window"

Tags: cocoa, dialog, messagebox, foreground, nsrunalertpanel

I'm trying to put together a simple error reporting package. If my main program crashes, it saves a crashlog, then starts a reporter program. The reporter program asks the user if it can send the crash log to me, then does so. I'm using NSRunAlertPanel to create a basic message box.

For some reason, that message box is showing up buried underneath any other windows that may be open. Run the main package from a Finder window, it shows up on top, force it to crash, the reporter window shows up *behind* the Finder window.

Why is this happening, and how can it be solved?

Minimal test case:

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

int main(int a, char* av) {
  NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  NSApplication* q = [[NSApplication alloc] init]; 
  NSRunAlertPanel(@"Hello", @"Aloha", @"OK", nil,nil);
  [pool release];
}
```

Built with:

```
g++ test.mm -framework AppKit && ./a.out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have come up with a solution, distilled from many tangentially-related webpages:

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

int main(int a, char* av) {
  NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  NSApplication* q = [[NSApplication alloc] init]; 

  ProcessSerialNumber psn = {0, kCurrentProcess};
  TransformProcessType(&psn, kProcessTransformToForegroundApplication);

  [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];

  NSRunAlertPanel(@"Hello", @"Aloha", @"OK", nil,nil);
  [pool release];
}
```

I do not pretend to understand this - it's cargo cult programming at its finest. Better answers, or explanations of what each step does, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's bringing your application to the front. Why you're doing this in main with no event loop, I have no idea.

Comment: The "application" is a 150-line program to ask the user a single question, do a few simple HTTP requests via curl, and possibly deliver a short message to the user. It doesn't really need a full-scale GUI, nor do I want one - I'd rather keep it as cross-platform as possible, all I really need is an equivalent to the Windows MessageBox().

Comment: It really doesn't matter what you want, the framework expects an event loop. Your struggle against this convention will more than likely be a complete waste of time.