# Bring NSRunAlertPanel Dialogue to Front in Background Process

Tags: cocoa, nsalert

If you call

```
NSRunAlertPanel()
```

from a background process in Cocoa, the dialogue does not come to the front and instead stays behind other windows.  This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639479/nsrunalertpanel-shows-up-behind-the-active-window) shows that you can bring the dialogue to the front if you convert the process to a foreground process.  If you keep the process a background process, however, is there any way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to do?  Background processes can still display UI and bring themselves to the front without using `TransformProcessType`; just make sure you are a `LSUIElement`, not `LSBackgroundOnly` (or the deprecated NS* equivalents).  The only reason you typically need to use `TransformProcessType` is if you want a Dock icon or menu bar.

Comment: I have a program running that has a presence in the menu bar.  When the program starts running, I want it to throw up a dialogue that asks the user whether or not they want to set the program to run at startup.  Right now calling `NSRunAlertPanel()` the dialogue comes up but is often hidden behind other windows.  How would I keep my program running with only a menu bar presence but make the dialogue come to the front of all the windows?

Comment: You need to bring your app to the front then: [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps: YES];